# Docker, issue with --force-recreate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate my_service
```

so that new img image is made and do not need to run whole `docker-compose`again.
but the thing is that there is still old data, i guess new img is not recreated.

tnx for help
miha

Comment: Please include your compose yml file and what data (files/directories) is being persisted.

Answer (score 0):

`--force-recreate` will force docker-compose to re-create the container, but it will not force docker-compose to rebuild the image. This is useful in case environment variable values changed by nothing else changed in the image for example.

To rebuild the image, you need to pass the `--build` option.

please refer to the original reference here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/